# products duplicate in shoppingcart

Tags: php, mysqli, shopping-cart

When I add multiple products to the shopping cart, it duplicates the product data which was first inserted. The prepare statement in showCart() also echo's 'There's something wrong', while the data is still displayed, I suppose my code looks quite nasty. Excuses for that, I'm planning on cleaning it, when I get it to function

```
public function displayProduct()
            {
                if($product = $this->db->query("SELECT id, title, description, price FROM trips ORDER BY id"))
                {

                        while ($row = $product->fetch_assoc())
                                {
                            $output[] = '<div class="reisbox">';
                                    $output[] = '<div id="reis_insidebox1">';
                            $output[] = '<div class="reis_textbox">';
                                $output[] = '<h2>'.ucfirst($row['title']).'</h2>';
                                            $output[] = '<article>';
                                                $output[] = ucfirst($row['description']);
                                            $output[] = '</article>';
                                    $output[] = '</div>';

                                    $output[] = '<div class="rightboxx">';
                                $output[] = '<div class="reis_price_box">';
                                            $output[] = '<div class="reis_price_box_text">';
                                                $output[] = '&euro;'.$row['price'];
                                        $output[] = '</div>';

                                        $output[] = '<div class="more_box">';
                                            $output[] = '<a href="index.php?page=reis"><p>Lees meer..</p></a>';
                                        $output[] = '</div>';
                                    $output[] = '</div>';
                                    $output[] = '</div>';
                                    $output[]='<br />';
                                    $output[] = '<div id="add">';
                                        $output[]='<a href="index.php?page=cart.php&action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a>';
                                    $output[] = '</div>';
                                        $output[] = '<div class="review_box">';
                                    $output[] = '<div class="review_text">Review</div>';

                                    $output[] = '<div class="review_textbox"> Fantastische ontvangst met kleine attenties. Fantastisch ontbijt,. Goede bedden en ruime zitgelegenheid in de serre.</div>';

                                    $output[] = '<div class="star_box"></div>';

                                    $output[] = '<div class="review_linkbox">';
                                        $output[] = '<a href="review1.php">Schrijf review</a>';
                                    $output[] = '</div>';
                                $output[] = '</div>';
                                $output[] = '</div>';


                    }
                    echo implode($output);
                }
```

```
public function showCart() {
        $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
        if ($cart) {
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $contents = array();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
            }
            $output[]='<div id="contents">';
            $output[] = '<form action="index.php?page=cart.php&action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
            $output[]='<table id="table_cart">';
            $output[]='<thead>';
            $output[]='<tr>';
            $output[]='<th scope="col"></th>';
            $output[]='<th scope="col">Informatie</th>';
            $output[]='<th scope="col">Prijs</th>';
            $output[]='<th scope="col">Aantal</th>';
            $output[]='<th scope="col">Prijs Totaal</th>';
            $output[]='</tr>';
            $output[]='</thead>';
            foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty)
            {
                $sql = 'SELECT id, title, description, price FROM trips WHERE id = ?';
                if($result = $this->db->prepare($sql))
                {
                    $result->bind_param('i', $id);
                    $result->execute();
                    $result->bind_result($id, $title, $description, $price);
                    $result->fetch();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "something went wrong";
                }
                $output[]='<tr>';
                $output[]='<td><a href="index.php?page=cart.php&action=delete&id='.$id.'" class="r"><p>Remove</p></a></td>';
                $output[]='<td>'.$title.'</td>';
                $output[]='<td>&euro;'.$price.'</td>';
                $output[]='<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
                $output[]='<td>&euro;'.($price * $qty).'</td>';
                $total += $price * $qty;
                $output[]='</tr>';


            }
            $output[] = '<div id="total">';
            $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>&euro;'.$total.'</strong></p>';
            $output[] = '<button type="submit">Update cart</button>';
            $output[] = '</div">';
            $output[] = '</table>';
            $output[]='</form>';
            $output[] = '</div">';
        } else {
            $output[] = '<p>You shopping cart is empty.</p>';
            $output[] = '<p><a href="index.php?page=reizen.php">terug naar reizen</a></p>';
        }
        return implode('',$output);
    }
```

Comment: This will need step-for-step debugging. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you adding all of your output to an array only to `implode` it to a string? This is much less efficient than simply concatenating the output. Basically, replace `$output[] = ` with `$output .=` and remove the `implode`

Comment: You really need to read up about [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s, and eliminate that array stuff. it just makes your code harder to read/follow.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is two separate bugs, and unless there is something else going on you aren't telling us the first script has nothing to do with either.

Bug 1: If your script echos `"something went wrong"` during a call `to showCart()` then you should be debugging your database connection and your statement prepare.  Unless some of those column names or the row name is wrong, the error will most likely be in your connection.  Try echoing the DB error info to see what is going on.

Bug 2: duplicated product data when showing cart:

To properly debug this we'd need to see how you add a product to the cart in the first place, but likely however you do so is interacting with this line negatively:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
            $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
        }
```

**EDIT**

Actually it probably isn't that line causing the second bug, it probably is the fact that you echo product info even if the DB call fails.